# Discord DataCord Server

Tags: discord

a server on Discord is an official server. The name of Discord's own server is datacord, but I can't find it anywhere. I'm posting the relevant pictures. The purpose of the server is to say on how many servers the new updates are activated.
・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・・
Merhaba, Discordun üzerinde bulunan bir sunucu resmi sunucu. Discordun kendi sunucusu ismi datacord ama hiç bir yerde bulamadım İlgili resimleri atıyorum sunucunun amacı yeni gelen güncellemelerin % kaç sunucuda aktifleştirildiğini söylemekte.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01IKA.jpg)

Comment: Your problem is unclear, try to modify your question: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I agree with @Giacomo. The title should not just repeat the tag, but contain the summary of the question

Comment: Then, don't duplicate the text in a language other than English. StackOverflow accepts questions in English only. Embed the image into the question, please. I suggest you add some code of your attempts. Do it with Edit, and your question will have better chances for being answered